# Unable to locate package latex-xcolor

Tags: installing, ubuntu

I am trying to install the package `latex-xcolor` on Ubuntu 18.04, by `sudo apt get latex-xcolor`, but I got a message saying `out: E: Unable to locate package latex-xcolor`.

It used to work on Ubuntu 16.04. Does anyone encounter the same issue? If this package is no longer supported on 18.04, what would be the replacement for that? Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The package manager doesn't have an entry for each LaTeX package (there are _thousands_ of them). Instead they are split into collections. Try `sudo apt install texlive-collection-latexrecommended `

Comment: @PhelypeOleinik I just tried it out, I got an error `E: Unable to locate package texlive-collection-latexrecommended` after the `sudo apt update`. Do I need extra repo for installing it? Thanks.

Comment: Hm, apparently the TeXLive package name doesn't match the Ubuntu repo package name. If I do `apt search texlive` there is `texlive-latex-recommended`, so try `sudo apt install texlive-latex-recommended`